# Unable to ping mikrotik interface ip

Tags: mikrotik

I have added the three network address on the lan interface, I'm able to ping two address, But unable to ping the 3rd address. I'm new to routing. I also have added the rip networks.

From which system I'm trying to ping the its ips are:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.10.15

Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0

IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.180

Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0

[image: Image showing address assigned to lan interface and ping output]

Comment: Why have you configured RIP here? Do you have multiple routers and need to exchange routes between them? Then, it looks like you have several IP networks in the same broadcast domain, which doesn't work.

Comment: on the same network we have two running scheme 192.168.0.0 and 10.10.10.0 on a single router. I want to route from 10.10.10.10 to 192.168.0.0 network thats why I have added a new ip on the lan interface. and added the RIP network. I'm new may be something is wrong. But When I added 172.x.x.x. I'm able to ping and i can't ping 192.168.0.2 which i have added on the lan interface of the mikrotik router

Comment: You will have issues with multiple IP subnets in same broadcast domain, so you should not do it.

Comment: Any Suggestions to communicate between two different networks. like 192.168.0.0/24 and 10.10.10.0/24

Comment: Have a separate broadcast domain set up for them. Two different physical networks, VLANs or similar.

Answer (score 0):

No routing protocols(sush as RIP) are needed, when there is only one broadcast network.

The problem is that your PC doesn't know where to send packets having 172.18.1.0/24 destination IP.

So you should just add mikrotik IP as gateway to your PC like this

Type this in cmd of your windows:

```
route add 172.18.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.2
```

> (Either 192.168.0.2 or 10.10.10.10)

Comment: I think the gateway needs to be the address which is already working.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the drawing board and rethink the problem. If I understand correctly, you have a single physical LAN with different device plugged into it. Some devices use 172.18.x.x addresses, some 192.168.x.x and some use 10.10.x.x. Correct? So that's 3 different LAN's. Treat them that way and plug 3 cables into 3 ports of the router. Note that ports are ports; they are labelled as LAN and WAN for convenience only. Go the "Bridge" menu and take out ports 2 & 3 from the LAN group so they become independent.

Now you have 4 networks; 3 LANs and 1 WAN. Proceed to set up inter-network routing as normal and everything will work.
With my Mikrotik, I have 2 LANs and 3 WANs, plus VPN.

No need to add any routing entries to individual PC's & servers. If a PC has the 10.10.10.20 IP, set the gateway to 10.10.10.10. If it has 196.168.0.20, set the gateway to 192.168.0.2.

Later on, I suggest you move all devices with 10.10.x.x IPs to one physical LAN (cable & switches), 192.168.0.x to second and so on.